# Google App Engine cron job sometimes fails due to too many retries

Tags: java, google-app-engine, cron

I have a Google App Engine cron job that often, but not always, fails because the max retries for a java servlet has been reached. The Google App Engine app works fine otherwise.

My servlet is shown below, and it usually reaches the "too many retries" point, but not always.

It is scheduled to run every few hours, and it seems like it may be failing due to waiting for an instance of the app to startup, but I don't know for sure.

How can I fix this?  Just increase the number of retries? How can I debug to know what is causing the "too many retries" to be reached?

```
public class SomeServlet extends BaseServlet {

        private static final String HEADER_QUEUE_COUNT = "X-AppEngine-TaskRetryCount";
        ...
        @Override
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
                        throws IOException {

                String retryCountHeader = req.getHeader(HEADER_QUEUE_COUNT);

                if (retryCountHeader != null) {
                        int retryCount = Integer.parseInt(retryCountHeader);
                        if (retryCount > 10) {
                                logger.severe("Too many retries, dropping task...");
                                taskDone(resp);
                                return;
                        }
                }
             ...
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It fails because the retryCount continues to increment every time the cron task is executed.  There is no control over retries for a Google App Engine cron task.  In the example above, once 10 cron jobs have been performed, the servlet will reach the "Too many retries" point.

Simply remove the retryCount testing and enqueue a real GAE task in the cron job if retry control is necessary.